# Converting xml message to idh file

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm passing an xml message from api endpoint. In middle of the mediation flow, I want to convert that xml message to a file with an extension with ".idh" (with a data mapping). After, that idh file has to pass to sftp file location. Could you please help me to do the file conversion part using wso2 esb?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what idh formnat looks like, but if you have already done the data mapping (xslt,smooks,js or whatever you used) then writing the file to a ftp server with .idh extension is simple. You just need to do the following.

1.) set your reply file name

```
<property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" value="yourFilename.idh" scope="transport"/>
```

2.) write it to the ftp using vfs

```
    <send>
<endpoint>
<address uri="vfs:sftp://user:pass@ftp.server.name/directory/"/>
</endpoint>
</send>
```

You can find more information here.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/VFS+Transport
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+271%3A+File+Processing